# if crash when comparing qstrings

Tags: c++, qt

I was trying to make a login and registration.
i am saving the credencials on text file, and for the login i use a if statement to compare what the user typed and the credencials saved on the file.
But my if is not working, the program crashes when it "enter".
currently my if is inside the while loop for the read file.
when i tryed to use it outside the `QString username and QString password` it was saying they where not declared.
here is the code:

```
        void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Login_clicked()
{
    QString usernamelogin = ui->lineEdit_username->text();
    QString passwordlogin = ui->lineEdit_password->text();

    QFile file("C:/Users/luisp/Desktop/poo/janela_de_login/Credencials/UsersInfo.txt");

     if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)){
        // QMessageBox::Warning(this,"Aviso", "file not open");
     }
    
     QTextStream in(&file);


while(!in.atEnd())
{
    QString line = in.readLine();
    QStringList credencials = line.split("\n");
    QString username = credencials[1];
    QString password = credencials[2];
    file.flush();
    file.close();

    if (username == usernamelogin && password == passwordlogin){
        //QMessageBox::information(this, "Login", "Username and password correct");
        ui->statusbar-> showMessage("Username e password correct", 3000);
    }
    else{
        //QMessageBox:: warning(this, "Login","Username e password not correct");
         ui->statusbar-> showMessage("Username e password not correct", 3000);
    }

}
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Register_clicked()
{
    QFile file("C:/Users/luisp/Desktop/poo/janela_de_login/Credenciais/UsersInfo.txt");

    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
       // QMessageBox::Warning(this,"warning", "file not open");
    }

    QTextStream out(&file);
    QString email = ui->Email_Register->text();
    out << email << '\n';
    QString username = ui->Username_Register->text();
    out << username << '\n';
    QString password = ui->Password_Register->text();
    out << password << '\n';

    file.flush();
    file.close();

}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Unrelated: I don't know `QTextStream`, but keep an eye on `while(!in.atEnd())`. It has the smell of a common bug where the stream is not in a bad state when tested because the previous read did not read to the end of the stream, but fails instantly on the next read because this read *does* find the end. Always read, test that the read succeeded, and only act on what was read if the read succeeded. What you have is test, read, always use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems I see, '\n' typically indicates a new line so is your username and password on different lines in the file? If not then obviously your problem is they are not on the same line. If you for some odd reason have username\npassword\n all in the same line, then you quite possibly are running off the end of the array returned by QString.split('\n') as it should return them in credentials[0] and credentials[1].

Comment: The use of `in.readLine();` on a text stream pretty much ensures they only got one of the required tokens if the delimiter is a new line. Worth noting that `readline` strips out the line delimiter, so the `split` will never find the delimiter and always return one token. Always do, test that you did, and only use the result of the do if the do did.

Comment: You are correct indeed!

Comment: Worth a quick edit to hammer home that the program probably failed at `QString username = credencials[1];` because there almost certainly is no `credencials[1]` and certainly failed at `QString password = credencials[2];` because there can't possibly be a `credencials[2]`. The failure may show up later at `if (username == usernamelogin && password == passwordlogin)` because, well, that's what Undefined Behaviour does: Something undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're wronging assuming that `line.split("\n")` call returns a list of 3 strings. It's impossible.

Your call `in.readLine()` read the file [till a trailing end-of-line character](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#readLine), and return the string without including the latter.

You are using an end-of-line character for store user credentials, this means that you are reading only one property of the user, and the split function return simply the read text row (the size of the QStringList var is equal to 1)

You can use the `readAll()` function instead

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Login_clicked()
{
   QString usernamelogin = ui->lineEdit_username->text();
   QString passwordlogin = ui->lineEdit_password->text();

   QFile file("C:/Users/luisp/Desktop/poo/janela_de_login/Credencials/UsersInfo.txt");

   if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
       return;
    
   QTextStream in(&file);
   QStringList userData = in.readAll().split("\n");
   if(userData.size() !== 3)
      return;

   QString userName = userData.at(1);
   QString userPass = userData.at(2);

   ...
}
```